# Spring WebFlux Security PreAuthorize Best Practice

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

as the title suggests, I have configured security in my Spring WebFlux application by using `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` and `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity`.

I am using `RouterFunction` to handle the request routing. The following code is for the router:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceRequestRouter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceRequestHandler requestHandler;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
        //@formatter:off
        return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/user/{userId}"), requestHandler::getUserDetails);
        //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

And the request handler is:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PreAuthorize("@userServiceRequestAuthorizer.authorizeGetUserDetails(authentication, #request)")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getUserDetails(ServerRequest request) {
        //@formatter:off
        return userService.getUserDetails(request.pathVariable("userId"))
            .convert()
            .with(toMono())
            .flatMap(
                (UserDetails userDetails) -> ServerResponse.ok()
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_NDJSON)
                    .body(Mono.just(userDetails), UserDetails.class)
            );
        //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `@Autowired` `UserService` is to fetch data from the database in a reactive way.

Next, I have defined a `@Component` as:

```
@Component
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Qualifier("userServiceRequestAuthorizer")
public class UserServiceRequestAuthorizer {

    public boolean authorizeGetUserDetails(JwtAuthenticationToken authentication, ServerRequest request) {
        // @formatter:off
        if (authentication == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Collection<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities()
            .stream()
            .map(Objects::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        if (roles.contains("Admin")) {
            return true;
        }

        Jwt principal = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String subject = principal.getSubject();
        String userId = request.pathVariable("userId");

        return Objects.equals(subject, userId);
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

It is notable here that I am using Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server, which is why the parameter `authentication` is of type `JwtAuthenticationToken`.

The application is working as per the expectation. But I am wondering if I am doing it the right way, meaning is this the best practice of doing method level `Authorization` in a **reactive** way?

The followings are my stack:

- JDK 17
- org.springframework.boot:3.0.0-M4
- org.springframework.security:6.0.0-M6

Any advice you could give would be much appreciated.

### Update

As mentioned by M. Deinum in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697747/spring-webflux-security-preauthorize-best-practice?noredirect=1#comment130140917_73697747) why shouldn't I use `hasAuthority("Admin") or principal.subject == #userId`, the reason is that the authorization code I provided is merely for demonstration purposes. It can get complicated and even if that complicacy might be managed by SpEL, I would rather not for the sake of simplicity.

Also the question is not about using inline SpEL, it's more about its reactiveness. I don't know if the SpEL mentioned in the `@PreAuthorize` is reactive! If it is reactive by nature then I can assume any expression mentioned in the `@PreAuthorize` would be evaluated reactively.

Comment: I would say no. Why not write an expression that doesn't require code? Something like `hasAuthority("Admin") or principal.subject == #userId`. No need to write custom code for each and every security check.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for providing the feedback. I have updated my question explaining why I would not be using SpEL. Because the authorization logic can be complicated. Even if SpEL can manage it, I would like to keep the `@PreAuthorize` statement simple.

Comment: No it isn't reactive as there is no reactive stuff in there, it is all blocking. Not sure how this is going to be called from the reactive security perspective (too little knowledge about that). But I would strongly suggest to not try to optimize before using SpEL else you get methods for each other method and you basically loose the benefit of Spring Security and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SpEL expressions evaluation is synchronous.

Unless your `UserServiceRequestAuthorizer` does more than checking access-token claims against static strings or request params and payload, I don't know why this would be an issue: it should be very, very fast.

Of course, if you want to check it against data from DB or a web-service this would be an other story, but I'd say that your design is broken and that this data access should be made once when issuing access-token (and set private claims) rather than once per security evaluation (which can happen several times in a single request).

### Side notes

> It is notable here that I am using Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server, which is why the parameter authentication is of type JwtAuthenticationToken.

I do not agree with that. It would be the same with any authorization-server (Keycloak, Auth0, Microsoft IdentityServer, ...). You have a `JwtAuthenticationToken` because you configured a resource-server with a JWT decoder and kept the default `JwtAuthenticationConverter`. You could configure any `AbstractAuthenticationToken` instead, as I do in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication).

> It can get complicated and even if that complicacy might be managed by SpEL, I would rather not for the sake of simplicity.

I join @M.Deinum point of view, writing your security rules in a service, like you do, makes it far less readable than inlining expressions: hard to guess what is checked while reading the expression => one has to quit current source file, open security service one and read the code.

If you refer to the [tutorial already linked above](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication), it is possible to enhance security DSL and write stuff like: `@PreAuthorize("is(#username) or isNice() or onBehalfOf(#username).can('greet')")` to stick to your sample, this would give `@PreAuthorize("is(#userId) or isAdmin())`.